# Restrictions on things brought into Ireland

Tags: customs-and-immigration, ireland

I am just wondering if I can bring brown sugar and mung bean starch into Ireland for personal use. Are there any cosmetics that are restricted when entering Ireland? What specific items are restricted when travelling to Ireland?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where you are travelling from depends on what the restrictions are.

Prohibited or restricted goods
Certain goods cannot be imported to Ireland or can only be imported under licence.

The main items that cannot be imported or must be imported under licence are:

- Firearms
- Ammunition
- Explosives and fireworks
- Offensive weapons
- Indecent or obscene material (books, periodicals, prints and video recordings)
- Plants or bulbs
- Live animals or dead animals (including cats and dogs)
- Birds, poultry or eggs
- Endangered species
- Meat and meat products, milk and milk products, and certain foodstuffs (with specific exceptions)
- Hay or straw (even if used as packing)
- Oral smokeless tobacco products (for example, Snus)

For cosmetics and Other goods (e.g. gifts, souvenirs, perfume, clothing, etc.) taken to Ireland from outside the EU:

- €430 per adult
- €215 per child under 15 years

I can see no restrictions on sugar, but recommend you check [this link](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/travel_and_recreation/travel_to_ireland/customs_regulations_for_travellers.html) for anything else specifically.

Comment: We have loads of brown sugar here already (granular, muscovado, whatever) , unless it's some specific type.